# Blender ball simulation question!

Tags: fluid-simulation, smoke-simulation, ocean-simulation

Do you know Maxim Zhestkov's artistic motion things?
https://youtu.be/NY4TGDP4C54

I'd like to make some alive balls like this link

Is it possible to make it in blender? I have the plan that balls turns some part of nature, tree, grass, waterfall.. as the link show us

I'd like to know if you have any tutorials or knowhow and possible.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

**Collider**

Add a box, Subdivide into a dense mesh, select one side vertices and assign them to a Vertex Group, add Displace modifier, choose Vertex Group, add New Texture > Voronoi, add Empty and use it for Texture Coordinates under modifier, animate Strenght and Empty location. Under Physics enable Collision (probably switch Normals orientation inward - red outside blue inside).

[image]

**Spheres**

Add a box of the same size, enable Particle system > Emission > Source > Volume > Grid. Add a Icosphere and use it as Render > Object > Icosphere.

Note in this example (standing object) I switched Gravity to -9.81  force in Y axis (not Z).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Plus question : If there is a box and turns to tree shapes with your reference, is it possible?

Comment: You can turn box into any shape displaced in one Axis from procedural or Black&White image texture. IT Is not clear what do you call 'tree" shape.